# How to seed a pivot database table with faker values in extra fields in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pivot, factory, seed, faker

I want to seed my database with faker values. I have 4 database tables: User, Order, Products and Order_Products. The last table is a pivot table between order and products. I added two fields to this pivot table: amount and price. Now i want to fill all these table with faker data. If i leave the two extra fields behind, it works with the code below. If i add the two extra fields in my migration. I get an error (obvious). But how do i fill in the extra fields from my Pivot table? Thanks in Advance.

It worked without the extra fields in my pivot table, but know i want the extra field filled as well with faker data.

### Factory Order

```
$factory->define(App\Order::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'orderdate' => now(),
        'amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2,0,6)
    ];
});
```

### Factory Product

```
$factory->define(App\Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'description' => $faker->sentence(),
        'price'=> $faker->randomFloat(2,0,6)
    ];
});
```

### Seeder

```
public function run()
{
   factory(App\User::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->orders()
                 ->saveMany(factory(App\Order::class, 2)
                 ->create(['user_id' => $user->id])
                 ->each(function ($order){
                      $order->products()
                      ->saveMany(factory(App\Product::class, 3)
                      ->create());
                      })
                      );
            });
}
```

### Migration Pivot Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');      
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->float('price',8,2);
    });

    Schema::table('order_product', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['order_id', 'product_id']);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 public function run ()
 {
  factory ( App\User::class, 5 )->create ()
     ->each ( function ( $user ) {
        $user->orders ()->saveMany ( factory ( App\Order::class, 2 )->create ( [ 'user_id' => $user->id ] )
              ->each ( function ( $order ) {
                 $products = factory ( App\Product::class, 3 )->make ();
                 foreach ( $products as $product )
                 {
                    $order->products ()->attach ( $product->id, [ 'amount' => 'xxx', 'price' => 'xxx' ] );
                 }
              } )
           );
     } );
```

}